# I can't cancel the event by the method of importing ics file in Outlook

Tags: outlook, icalendar

When I create an iCalendar on Outlook, I want to delete it on Outlook with importing the ics-cancel-file,but it gives me the message "The events could't be imported. Please try again later.Error message".

The event ics file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 15.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20160504T072433Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE;VALUE=DATE:20160506
SUMMARY:BirthDay
UID:20160504T072432Z-1@fe80:0:0:0:a2d3:c1ff:fe34:bacf%2
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The ics-cancel-file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 15.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20160504T072433Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE;VALUE=DATE:20160506
SUMMARY:BirthDay
UID:20160504T072432Z-1@fe80:0:0:0:a2d3:c1ff:fe34:bacf%2
STATUS:CANCELLED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

What can I fix it that I can delete the event? What's wrong with this ics file?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you finally find a way to cancel it?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the 2nd file just change the Event's `STATUS,` which defines the overall status or confirmation for the calendar component (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.11)

The only way there is for deleting a calendar object if by a `DELETE Request` (http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc2518.html#METHOD_DELETE). So there isn't something wrong with the `.ics` file.

Comment: A HTTP DELETE request can't be applied in Outlook because a HTTP request needs a HTTP server. An ICS can be imported in Outlook (or Thunderbird, Google Calendar) from the file system., I tested a CANCEL and it works as expected in Google Calendar